# bin float precision numbers according to exponent

Tags: floating-point

What is a good way to bin float precision numbers?
something like this, but perhaps more efficient?

```
x = 1;
for i = 0,size-1 {  // loop over number of bins
    if (value > x) {
        ++bin[i]; return;
    }
    x *= 0.1;
}
++bin[size-1]; // increment last bins
```

I have thought of getting exponent directly, `frexp`, and using that.
Is it worthwhile?

Comment: You ask for a good way to bin numbers, but you don't describe the numbers. Tom's answer below could be a good solution, unless all numbers are between 0 and 10... Perhaps you could describe why you want to do this to help with understanding what the best solution would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this question, I think it might help you:

"Given a number x, what is the exponent when x is written in scientific notation.  For example, if x is .007, the exponent is -3 (7x10^-3)."

So, x = a * 10^b, with 1 <= a < 10.  We solve for b.

Let's take the log (base 10) of both sides

- log(x) = log(a * 10^b)
- log(x) = log(a) + log(10^b)
- log(x) = log(a) + b
- b = log(x) - log(a)

Now b is an integer, and 0 <= log(a) < 1, so log(a) is really just the fractional part of log(x).  So, we can just drop the fractional part by rounding log(x) down.

- b = floor(log(x))

When x = .007, b = floor(-2.15) = -3 as expected

I think the C code would be **int b = (int) floor( log10( x ) )**